# Modifying an ActiveRecord model with a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just learning RoR and I've run into a problem in my unit tests where a simple function I wrote will not modify it's object appropriately. I must be missing something very basic because I have seen this question on any forum.

I run my test with rake via "rake test test/functional/song_test.rb". The data is loaded from a yaml file and that seems to be correct. But when I call my "vote!" function (see below) to modify an attribute, @rating, the change is not visible in the test and my assertion fails.

```
test "vote!" do
  song1 = songs(:song1)                         # 'songs' was loaded from a yaml file
  assert song1.respond_to?('vote!'), "Can't vote!()!"
  assert_equal 5, song1.rating, "Rating is wrong"  # assertion passes

  song1.vote!(1)

  assert_equal 1, song1.rating, "Rating should be 1" # assertion fails
end
```

Here is the failure message:

```
SongTest#test_vote! = 0.00 s                         
  1) Failure:
test_vote!(SongTest) [/test/functional/song_test.rb:35]:
Rating should be 1.
<1> expected but was
<5>.
```

I verified with puts() that the change does occur within the vote! function. But after the function returns the song1.rating value has not changed. Here's the class with the vote! function.

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :rating, :presence => true

  def vote!(num_stars)
    @rating = num_stars
  end
end
```

I'm thinking that there are two copies of the object somehow and the vote! function is invoked on a temporary object. But I don't see how or why that would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rating` attribute and the `@rating` instance variable are not related. Your `vote!` method should look like:

```
def vote!(num_stars)
  self.rating = num_stars
end
```

What you're doing in your existing code is creating an instance variable that isn't used.

As a note, by convention a method called `vote!` would have the effect of saving the changes made to the model. For example:

```
self.update_attribute(:rating, num_stars)
```